# Scale an equation to fit exact page width

Tags: latex

I have an equation that is only a tiny bit too wide for one line. I'd really like to avoid having the equation number on the next line. How do you achieve this? Currently I'm using `\small`, but this is overkill.

**Please note.** I have tried `scalebox` and `fittowidth` but get errors about missing `\endgroup`. I have also used `\!` to its full extent. I am hoping for a solution that will allow me to scale the proper one-line equation to the width of the page.

Here is an example (not my actual equation):
[image: Long equation]

Comment: Are there any unnecessary characters in the equation you could delete? Any way you could rewrite it to be a little shorter? (Just in case nobody comes along with a real solution)

Comment: Also, why not use amsmath's `split` for equations or a `multiline`? Everything else will be a pain to read anyway.

Comment: If you can, I think you should define some functions and variables to shorten the main expression down. It can be hard to read and understand such a long expression anyway.

Comment: My actual equation is quite simple. It is inflated due to function names and subscripts with names (like 'x_\mathrm{min}`). You guys are right in general; my question is specific, if perhaps a little theoretical.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

```
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{.9\hsize}{!}{$A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z$}
\end{equation}
```

or

```
\begin{equation}
\resizebox{.8\hsize}{!}{$A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z$}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: +1 So, I was really close with `scalebox`. Why does it have to be inside the equation environment? Also, why am I then forced to use in-line math mode instead of display style? Thanks for this good answer.

Comment: `Why does it have to be inside the equation environment?` It is not necessary. As you wish. For example. `Also, why am I then forced to use in-line math mode instead of display style?` Because `\resizebox` deals with box and you have to form such box. Any math inside horizontal box is text mode math.

Comment: @AlexeyMalistov Can you use this also to reduce the size of only a part of a centered equation? Like `$$aaa=\resizebox{...}{!}bbb$$`.

Comment: Attempted to use this with `p_{x,y}(t)=\varepsilon\cdot\Big[(1-\delta)\cdot p_{x,y}(t-1)+\Delta p_{x,y}(t-1,t)+d_{x,y}(t-1,t)\Big]` which failed. Thus I do not consider this a solution to the general problem.

Comment: This solution does not explain that the `graphicx` package must be loaded in for it to work

Comment: Is it possible to do a similar trick with multline somehow? Naively it throws an error.

Answer (score 9):

I just had the situation that I wanted this only for lines exceeding `\linewidth`, that is: Squeezing long lines slightly.
Since it took me hours to figure this out, I would like to add it here.

> **I want to emphasize that scaling fonts in LaTeX is a deadly sin!
>   In nearly every situation, there is a better way (e.g. `multline` of the `mathtools` package). So use it conscious.**

In this particular case, I had no influence on the code base apart the preamble and some lines slightly overshooting the page border when I compiled it as an eBook-scaled pdf.

```
\usepackage{environ}         % provides \BODY
\usepackage{etoolbox}        % provides \ifdimcomp
\usepackage{graphicx}        % provides \resizebox

\newlength{\myl}
\let\origequation=\equation
\let\origendequation=\endequation

\RenewEnviron{equation}{
  \settowidth{\myl}{$\BODY$}                       % calculate width and save as \myl
  \origequation
  \ifdimcomp{\the\linewidth}{>}{\the\myl}
  {\ensuremath{\BODY}}                             % True
  {\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\ensuremath{\BODY}}}  % False
  \origendequation
}
```

---

Before
[image: before]
After
[image: after]

Comment: upvoted for "scaling fonts in LaTeX is a deadly sin" !

Answer (score 4):

The [`graphicx` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) provides the command `\resizebox{width}{height}{object}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\hrule
%%%
\makeatletter%
\setlength{\@tempdima}{\the\columnwidth}% the, well columnwidth
\settowidth{\@tempdimb}{(\ref{Equ:TooLong})}% the width of the "(1)"
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-\the\@tempdimb}% which cannot be used for the math
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-1em}%
% There is probably some variable giving the required minimal distance
% between math and label, but because I do not know it I used 1em instead.
\addtolength{\@tempdima}{-1pt}% distance must be greater than "1em"
\xdef\Equ@width{\the\@tempdima}% space remaining for math
\begin{equation}%
\resizebox{\Equ@width}{!}{$\displaystyle{% to get everything inside "big"
 A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K+L+M+N+O+P+Q+R+S+T+U+V+W+X+Y+Z}$}%
\label{Equ:TooLong}%
\end{equation}%
\makeatother%
%%%
\hrule
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an addition to the answer by Stephen: I use something like

```tex
\resizebox{\minof{\width}{\myeqwidth}}{!}{%
  a = b
}
```

together with the `calc` package (which provides `\minof`). It seems `\width` refers to the original width of the box (https://latexref.xyz/_005cresizebox.html), and `\myeqwidth` is a latex length e.g. defined as `\textwidth - 2cm`. Thus, if the equation is narrow enough, it is not scaled. If it is too wide, it is scaled to `\myeqwidth`.